# MediaPlayer Won't Play Next Song Automatically

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I tried everything, and nothing works... I tried many codes from stackflow and still nothing:
[MediaPlayer play songs serially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648088/mediaplayer-play-songs-serially)
[Android app force closes when playing next song in array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872763/android-app-force-closes-when-playing-next-song-in-array-list)
etc...

I just need from mediaplayer to play next songs automatically.
This is my code now:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

final String songs_url[] = {
        "http://www.aap.nl/images/stories/audio/am2012-10sec-bel.mp3",
        "http://www.cse.org.uk/downloads/file/42187%20CSE%20-%20Free%20loft%20&%20Cavity%20Wall%20Insulation%20-%2010%20sec.mp3",
        "http://soundsleepstudio.com/soundsleep/Sounds/washing-machine-10-sec.mp3"
};

private TextView SongTitle;
private int counter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //fullscreen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    counter = 0;
    final ImageButton btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playAndPauseButton);
    SongTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSongTitle);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SongTitle.setText(songs_url[counter]);

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songs_url[0]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songs_url[counter]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how it is failing?

Comment: crash, play first song again and again when i click play, play first song and then stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just set a new datasource for the MediaPlayer. You first need to reset it and then set the datasource. Example:

```
   mediaPlayer.reset();
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songs_url[counter]);
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
   mediaPlayer.start();
```